# Select all instances from ontology that have a relationship to a given instance

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, ontology, protege

I developed an ontology about machine learning using Protege. 
I have the following classes with their instances:

- Algorithm : A1, A2
- LearningMethod : M1, M2

An algorithm can have *has-learning-method* object property to a learning method.

I want to build a query to select all learning methods assigned for instance A1.

I managed to build a query that gives me all the instances of Algorithm with their corresponding LearningMethod.

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX ml: <http://www.semanticweb.org/machine-learning-ontology#>


SELECT DISTINCT ?x0 ?x1 WHERE {
  ?x0 rdf:type ml:Algorithm.
  ?x1 rdf:type ml:LearningMethod.
  ?x0 ml:has-learning-method ?x1.
}
```

Given answer:

```
+---------+---------+
|    x0   |    x1   |
+---------+---------+
|    A1   |    M1   |
+---------+---------+
|    A2   |    M2   |
+---------+---------+
```

How can I select only the learning methods linked to A1? 
Is there any prefix i could use?

The expected result should be:

```
+---------+---------+
|    x0   |    x1   |
+---------+---------+
|    A1   |    M1   |
+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Just write the URI of A1 (I guess it's `ml:A1`) instead of each occurrence of `?x0` ? Or use a filter, i.e. `FILTER(?x0 = ml:A1)` if you also want the column for bindings of `?x0` with value `ml:A1` in the result

Comment: Thank you! I tried the first option and it worked